# how to plot timespace using matlab or seaborn and have different color coding based on values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, timespace

I want to plot timespace with x-axis - timestamp , y-axis - id's and the line plotted , whose color would change base on the value of another field which is currState.
I have the data in csv format and have used pandas to convert the data into dataframes. What I want is x-axis to have time at 1 minute interval, the color of the line should change based on currState(3 - green ,5- red, 6- yellow).

Sample data -

```
timestamp                                       currState          IntersectionId    
2020-02-26 16:12:13.131484                        3                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:14.131484                        3                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:15.131484                        3                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:16.131484                        5                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:17.131484                        5                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:18.131484                        5                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:19.131484                        6                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:20.131484                        6                    12345
2020-02-26 16:12:21.131484                        6                    12345
```

[the sample plot in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSj9K.png)

Comment: Hi Shruti. Please add a [minimum, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you've been trying to use as stated on the [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the SO documentation.

Comment: I am new to python matplotlib and seaborn and hence havent been able to do much as such to do the plot. I have the data in the pandas datframe format with the timestamp_verbose as index and what I need to do is plot timestamp vs intersectionId with the color changing based on the currState so if the state in 2 or 3 the color is red, 5 or 6 its yellow and 7 or 8 its blue. I tried to do it with the bar charts but seem to have issues with it, or I dont understand how to do them. If anyone can shed some inputs that would be great